# Isolate portion of fasta sequence from external count data

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I am trying to isolate a portion of a fasta sequence using count data from a separate txt file.

I entered the fasta into the def analyze_seq function. When I use this code, it seems to work, but I get everything in the print statement in a vertical list, one nucleotide at a time. I want the id and each associated group of bps printed in horizontal lines

```
import re

def analyze_seq(id, seq, fname="FPT_REAL_unique.txt"):
  with open(fname) as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
      columns = line.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
      qid, qstart, qend, gap_length = columns
      if qid == id:
        count2 = 0
        for seq_item in seq:
            count2 += 1
            if int(qstart) >= count2 <=int(qend):
                print(id + "\t" + seq_item)


my_file = open("Galaxy55-[Tabular-to-FASTA_on_data_54].fasta" , "r")

id = ''
seq = ''
count = 0

for x in my_file:
    if re.search(r"^>", x):
        if id != '':
            analyze_seq(id, seq)
            count = count + 1
        id = x.rstrip("\n")
        seq = ''
    else:
        seq = seq + x.rstrip("\n")
```

I also tried

```
print(id + "\t" + y[str(qstart):str(qend)])
```

and got this error: TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method

```
The output I am looking for will look like this:
>Trinity124124    AGCTAGCTAGCTAGCTA
>Trinity182537    AGCTAGCTAGCTACGTA
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and add sample input and expected output?

Comment: Why `[str(qstart):str(qend)]`? You turn `qstart` and `qend` into strings, and the error message complains that indexing should be done by integers. I bet it's a typo and you meant `[int(qstart) : int(qend)]`. Aslo consider `qid, qstart, qend, gap_length = columns` to unpack. Also you lose stripping; you wanted `columns = x.rstrip('\n').split('\t')`.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is printing ids related to each seq on one line, print them without a newline, and add a newline after the group.

Try something like this:

```py
def analyze_seq(id, seq, fname="FPT_REAL_unique.txt"):
  with open(fname) as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
      columns = line.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
      qid, qstart, qend, gap_length = columns
      if qid == id:
        count = 0
        bps = []
        for seq_item in seq:
          count += 1
          if count <= int(qstart) <= int(qend):  # I suppose this is more correct?
            bps.append(id)
        if bps:  # Something was associated with qid.
          print(id, '\t', ' '.join(bps))  # bps are space-separated; alter to taste.
```

Comment: So the count that I'm looking for is in between qstart and qend, I'm not sure that what you have here will do that... Also, I'm not quite sure what your response #something was associated with qid means. Thank you for helping to streamline the code above that though!